# How can i upload Photo from imagePickerController using ASIFormDataRequest?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

I use the delegate of UIImagePickerController for choosing a photo and put it to the server but the problem is i don't know how can i do that using ASIFormDataRequest and i don't know what key should use for the info parameter?

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.siteweb.com/api/v2/businesses/%@/pics.xml",entry.permalink];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.delegate = self;

[request startAsynchronous];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

> [request addFile:(NSString *)filePath forKey:(NSString *)key];

Get the image like this beforehand:

> UIImage *image = (UIImage *) [info
>   valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
>
> [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:filePath
>   atomically:YES];

Comment: I must use imagePickerController so what can i do for the path using the info parameter?